# How do I get the target branch?

Tags: bitbucket, bamboo

How do I get the target branch of a pull request in Bamboo (version 6.8.0)? The pull request was created on Bitbucket (version 6.8.0). I need the target to pass to Sonarqube, but I can't find a variable that has it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved at Bamboo 6.9.0, see https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-18350.

There're `repository.pr.sourceBranch` and `repository.pr.targetBranch` build variables

Comment: Thanks. I would really like to upgrade, but we're moving to Jenkins soon so that isn't an option. In the mean time I need to find a way to get this in 6.8.